# How do i associate multiple events to a specific day, in php/mysql?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, calendar

Basically I'm trying to build by myself a booking system for a gym.

I would like to generate an "event calendar" where i can associate to a specific day (date) different gym-classes (time) and also modify the classes time if necessary like add or cancel classes.
I didn't use a `<form>` because i don't want to compile every field manually(is it there a way to pre-compile a form and fetch the data in order to send them to a database?).

So my solution at the moment is just a html table where i can choose the days period:

**createPeriod.php**:

```
 $data_inizio= $_POST["inizio"];
 $data_fine=$_POST["fine"];

$begin = new DateTime($data_inizio);
$end = new DateTime($data_fine);
$end = $end->modify( '+1 day' );

$interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
$daterange = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval ,$end);
```

Let the user choose the period in **amdminpanel.php:**

```
<div class="insert-date col-xl-10 col-lg-9 ml-auto">
        <h1>Date Manager</h1>

        <form action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
          <label>Inserisci data inizio:</label>
          <input type="date" id="inizioCalendario" name="inizio" >
          <label>Inserisci data fine:</label>
          <input type="date" id="fineCalendario" name="fine" >
          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Genera">
        </form>
        <hr>
```

Then i hardcoded in an array the most used gym-classes time:

```
$lezioni=array("7.30-8.30","8.30-9.30","13.00-14.00","17.30-18.30","18.30-19.30","19.30-20.30","20.30-21.30");
```

and put all together in **adminpanel.php** again:

```
<h2>Calendario</h2>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Giorni</th>
    <th>Lezione 1</th>
    <th>Lezione 2</th>
    <th>Lezione 3</th>
    <th>Lezione 4</th>
    <th>Lezione 5</th>
    <th>Lezione 6</th>
    <th>Lezione 7</th>

  </tr>
    <?php
    foreach($daterange as $date){
        echo "<tr>" .
          "<td>".$date->format("d/m/Y")."</td>";
        foreach($lezioni as $stringa){
            echo
          "<td>".$stringa."</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>";
    }

     ?></td>

</table>
```

and here is the final result:
[image: admin Panel]

But now i don't have any idea how to modify or cancel classes and fetch the data in order to store it in 2 mysql tables.
Any suggestions?
If possible, i would avoid to use already done github projects/calendars.
Thank you

p.s.
I know that my code might be bad, as you can easily tell I'm still learning.
Thank you.

**Update**

I did some research and I will try to do it with JavaScript, anyone can suggest some good documentation/tutorial for this?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

so you want to modify the table or delete from it

i suggest you to use java script and in special ajax technology

and take these step :

1-declare class name for every cell in same raw in table when generate table using php and to be easy
make the class name as it  in the MySql database and give every cell an id as it value in mysql database and declare a function and but it on the cell so if one click to cell to edit it it show prompt box to enter anew value this function take the cell calss name and it's id and send it to javascript function which make request to php file which response to handle the class name and id that as we say same as in mysql data base and then it generate sql statement and sql query to update it in database and at the end of the function put statment to reload the page and load the new table

this is the simplist way you can make another js function for another cell which it to delete all row from database

so i make an example for you and you just want to made an update_event.php which hande data from request and update it to my sql and also :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<table style="border:1px solid green;width:100%;">
<tr>

<td class="227_2020" id="22/7/2020" onclick="update_event(this.id,this.className);">22/7/2020</td>
<td  class="227_2020" onclick="update_event(this.id,this.className);" id="20:16">20:16 </td>
<td  class="22_7_2020"  onclick="update_event(this.id,this.className)" id="21:16">21:16</td>


</tr>

</table>

</body>
<script>
function update_event(id,class_name){
var new_date= prompt("please enter new date :");
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        alert("update new value is done");
        location.reload();
      }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "update_event.php?q="+new_date+"&id="+id, true);//here is the request that js make wich contain data to update using update_event.php
    xmlhttp.send();
  }

</script>
</html>


''''
```

[simple code to explain waht to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KW2Mr.png)

Answer (score 0):

The problem you will face is that you're looping to generate days and time classes. This reduces your felxibility to manage them individually.

You should start by reconfiguing your database to have an events table which would have a date and a lezione number. But this approach would only work if you were certain that the lezione times would NEVER change. (I would advise using a datetime range and event name.
event_id, event_datetime_start, event_datetime_end, event_name)

Then, you would use PHP to build an associative array which would loop through dates that you wanted to view in your admin panel.

It would loop through days and then loop through lezione on that day. If an event wasn't generated for the lezione number on that day, it wouldn't show up. You could make a button in place of it which would auto generate an event to that day and lezione number.

It also provides you with an event_id to which you can bind other elements (attendance, instructors etc).

I would recommend building this in JS, it would make for a much cleaner experience. But for now you should be able to do most of this in PHP until you get the fundamentals down.

See below for a VERY basic JS mockup.

PS. Apologies for misuse of lezione/lezioni/language

```js
//JS array where you would have a DB - in JS you would make an ajax call to fetch this.
let lezioneevents = {
  1:{'lezione':1, 'date':1},
  2:{'lezione':2, 'date':1},
  3:{'lezione':3, 'date':1},
  4:{'lezione':4, 'date':1},
  5:{'lezione':1, 'date':2},
  6:{'lezione':2, 'date':2},
  7:{'lezione':3, 'date':2},
  8:{'lezione':4, 'date':3},
  9:{'lezione':1, 'date':3},
  10:{'lezione':1, 'date':4},
  11:{'lezione':2, 'date':4},
  12:{'lezione':4, 'date':4},
  };
let lezioni_list = {
  '1':"7.30-8.30",
  '2':"8.30-9.30",
  '3':"13.00-14.00",
  '4':"17.30-18.30",
  '5':"18.30-19.30"
};
table = '<table border="1">'

//Header row
table+= '<tr><td>Glomi</td>';
for (lezion_id in lezioni_list){
    table+= '<td>Lezione '+lezion_id+'</td>'
}
table+= '</tr>'

for (i = 1; i < 6; i++){  //I'm mocking up the dates for simplicity
  table+= '<tr><td nowrap>2020 Jul 0'+i+'</td>'
  for(lezione_id in lezioni_list){//Loop through your list of lezioni
   anyevents = get_event(i, lezione_id)
   table+= '<td>'+anyevents+'</td>'
  }
  table+= '</tr>'
}
table+= '</table>'

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = table;

function get_event(event_date, lezione_id){ 
// loop through events to find any matches for today. Note this is an inefficient way to do this, but simply for examples sake. 
// Much better off using an associative array, but one step at a time.
  for(lezioneevent_id in lezioneevents){
    if (lezioneevents[lezioneevent_id].date==event_date&&lezioneevents[lezioneevent_id].lezione==lezione_id){
      return 'Event:'+lezioneevent_id+''
    }
  }
    return '<button type="button">Add</button>'
}
```

```html
<div id='demo'></div>
```